# What does $\mathbb{C}[G ]\otimes_{\mathbb{C}[H]} W$ mean?

Tags: group-theory, notation, representation-theory, representation-of-algebras

I am reading the group representation book by Serre. In chapter 7 (which is about induced representation), he introduces the notation

$$ \mathbb{C}[G] \otimes_{\mathbb{C}[H]} W .$$

What does this notation mean? I understand $W$ as a $H$-module, or a representation of $H$. I also can accept $\mathbb{C}[G] \otimes  W$ as a tensor product space of $(\sum_{g\in G} a_g g , w)$, where $w\in W$. But how to understand the $ \mathbb{C}[H] $ in the subscript?

Comment: [Wikipedia on tensor products over a ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_modules). You may be thinking of / familiar with tensor products over $\Bbb{C}$ (or a field). Here there will be more cancellations due to the rules
$$a\otimes rw=ar\otimes w$$ for all $a\in\Bbb{C}[G]$, $r\in\Bbb{C}[H]$, $w\in W$.

Comment: Because $\Bbb{C}[H]$ is a free right module over $\Bbb{C}[H]$ with a basis consisting of a set of representatives $D\subset G$ of cosets $gH$. This tensor product becomes a left $\Bbb{C}[G]$-module because $\Bbb{C}[G]$ itself is a bimodule: $\Bbb{C}[G]$ acts on it by multiplication from the left, and $\Bbb{C}[H]$ acts on it by multiplication from the right, and the two actions commute. The end result is called *the induced representation of $G$,* $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(W)$.

Comment: Sheesh :-( ^$\Bbb{C}[G]$ is a free right $\Bbb{C}[H]$-module etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $R$ be a ring.
Given a right $R$-module $M$ and left $R$-module $N$, we can form the tensor product $M ⊗_R N$.
This tensor product can be described as the abelian group with generators $m ⊗ n$, where $m$ and $n$ range through $M$ and $N$ respectively, subject to the the relations
\begin{align*}
  (m_1 + m_2) ⊗ n &= m_1 ⊗ n + m_2 ⊗ n \,, \\
  m ⊗ (n_1 + n_2) &= m ⊗ n_1 + m ⊗ n_2 \,, \\
  (m r) ⊗ n &= m ⊗ (r n)
\end{align*}
for all $m, m_1, m_2 ∈ M$, $n, n_1, n_2 ∈ N$, $r ∈ R$.

Let now $S$ be another ring and let $M$ not just be a right $R$-module, but actually an $S$-$R$-bimodule.
The tensor product $M ⊗_R N$ can then be made into a left $S$-module such that
$$
  s ⋅ (m ⊗ n) = (s m) ⊗ n
$$
for all $s ∈ S$, $m ∈ M$, $n ∈ N$.

Let us consider the special case that $R$ is a subring of $S$.
We can then regard $S$ as an $S$-$R$-bimodule.
For every left $R$-module $M$ we can thus form the left $S$-module $S ⊗_R M$.
This construction of going from left $R$-modules to $S$-modules is the *extension of scalars from $R$ to $S$*.
It satisfies the adjunction
$$
  \operatorname{Hom}_S( S ⊗_R M, N )
  ≅
  \operatorname{Hom}_R( M, N )
$$
for every left $R$-module $M$ and every left $S$-module $N$.
(On the right hand side, we regard $N$ as a left $R$-module by restriction of scalars.)

Suppose now that $G$ is a group, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, and $V$ is a representation of $H$.
We would like to extend the representation $V$ into a representation of $G$.
In other words, we would like to extend the $ℂ[H]$-module $V$ to a $ℂ[G]$-module.
The group algebra $ℂ[H]$ is a subalgebra of the group algebra $ℂ[G]$, so we can use the extension of scalars
$$
  ℂ[G] ⊗_{ℂ[H]} V
$$
to solve this problem.
This is then called the *induced representation of $V$ from $H$ to $G$*, and often denoted by $\operatorname{Ind}^G_H(V)$.
This induced representation satisfies the adjunction
$$
  \operatorname{Hom}_G( \operatorname{Ind}^G_H(V), W )
  =
  \operatorname{Hom}_{ℂ[G]}( ℂ[G] ⊗_{ℂ[H]} V, W )
  ≅
  \operatorname{Hom}_{ℂ[H]}( V, W )
  =
  \operatorname{Hom}_H( V, W )
$$
for every representation of $V$ of $H$ and every representation $W$ of $G$.
In this context of group representations, this adjunction is often referred to as *Frobenius reciprocity*.

More details about tensor products and extension of scalars can, for example, be found in section 10.4 of *Abstract Algebra* (3rd edition) by Dummit and Foote.